# Swift 3 / How to use result of warning "Result of call is unused"

Tags: ios, swift

*Before marking as duplicate: I have researched and found plenty of threads to this topic, but all of them solve it by silencing the warning with `_ =`. I don't want to silence the warning. I want to use the result!*

I'm trying to convert a forked Framework to Swift 3 and am stuck at the warning:

> Result of call is unused

At the following code:

```
func setupViews() {
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.autoLayoutToSuperview()   // here, result of autoLayoutToSuperview() is unused
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

`autoLayouttoSuperview` is a function of that Framework that returns an Array of `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```
func autoLayoutToSuperview(_ attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.left, .right, .top, .bottom], inset: CGFloat = 0) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

    var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    for attribute in attributes {

        var constant = inset
        switch attribute {
        case .right:
            constant = -inset
        case .bottom:
            constant = -inset
        default:
            break
        }

        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self,
            attribute: attribute,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self.superview,
            attribute: attribute,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: constant
        )
        self.superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
        constraints.append(constraint)
    }

    return constraints
}
```

I am able to silence the warning, but since the result will not get used, the `imageView` does not appear in the wanted appearance.

Pic image:

[image]

Use it:

[image]

`imageView` with incorrect appearance.

[image]

How do I use the result? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might say:

```
let constraints = imageView.autoLayoutToSuperview()
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```